# Does a finite group always contains subgroups generated by its elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Does a finite group contains subgroups generated by its elements.

I suspect that answer is Yes and  that my question could be trivial. But I am studying algebra for the first time so I wanted to be sure. I would really appreciate your input.

While proving that a group of prime order is cyclic (2.2.4 page 60 Herstein) it has been mentioned that if $a\in G$, $a\neq e$ then the power of $a$ forms a subgroup $(a)$ of $G$ different than $(e)$. And then the the proof is completed easily.

I agree that the power of $a$ forms a cyclic group $(a)$ but what is the guarantee that $G$ will always contain such a subgroup.

May be I should edit my question little bit now in light of your answer. If $a \in  G$ then what is the guarantee that a cyclic subgroup $(a)$ exist. Could not " $a$ " be an element of $G$ but not generate any group. Again it could be a trivial thing to ask but better safe than sorry.

Comment: If the group contains $a$ and $a^n$, then by closure it contains $a^{n+1}$. So if it contains $a$, it must contain $a^2$, so it must contain $a^3$, and so on.

Comment: For future reference: another option besides asking others is thinking about it yourself. In math you will need to depend on yourself a lot.

Comment: There is only one identity element $e \in G$ (you may have seen this proved already). If $G$ contains more than one element, there must be some $a \in G$ with $a \neq e.$ Now $a^{2} \neq ae (=a)$, otherwise we could multiply by $a^{-1}$ to get $a =e.$ Hence the powers of $a$ form a subgroup with more than one element.

Comment: For a rigorous proof, you need to first define what you mean by "generated by..." That's the trick, and then you need to prove that the definition yields a subgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any collection of elements in a group, finite or infinite, always generates some subgroup. This is in particular always true for a single element of the group. Sometimes, however, the generated subgroup may be the entire group. (But any group is a subgroup of itself, so this is not a contradiction).

To see this, we first need a *definition* of what it means to generate a subgroup. Typically it would be something like this:

> Let $G$ be a group, and let $A\subseteq G$ be any set of elements of $G$ (in particular $A$ may consist of a single element, $A=\{a\}$). We say that the subgroup $H$ of $G$ is *generated by* $A$ iff
>
> - $A\subseteq H$, that is, every element of $A$ is in $H$, *and*
> - For every subgroup $K$ such that $A\subseteq K$, it holds that $H\subseteq K$
>
> (in other words, $H$ must be the *smallest* subgroup that contains $A$).

With this definition it clear that $A$ generates *at most* one subgroup (because if $H_1$ and $H_2$ both satisfy the condition, then we must have $H_1\subseteq H_2$ and $H_2\subseteq H_1$, which together mean that $H_1=H_2$). But it is not immediately obvious that *every* $A$ *always* generates some subgroup.

In order to prove that it does, we can first prove a **lemma**: Let $S$ be any collection of subgroups of $G$. Then the set
$$ \bigcap S = \{ x\in G \mid (\forall H\in S) x\in H \}$$
is a subgroup of $G$. This is fairly easy to show -- for example, if $a$ and $b$ are both in $\bigcap S$, then it must be because $a$ and $b$ are both in each subgroup that is in $S$. But then, by definition of subgroup, $ab$ must be in each of the subgroups in $S$, too, so $ab\in\bigcap S$.

Now, given, $A$ apply the lemma with $S$ being the collection of all subgroups that has $A$ as a subset. I claim that $\bigcap S$ is generated by $A$. We know that $\bigcap S$ is a subgroup. Additionally for every $a\in A$, we know by construction that $a$ is in each of the subgroups in $S$, which means that $a$ is also in $\bigcap S$. So $A\subseteq \bigcap S$.

The second condition for being a generates subgroup now requires that $\bigcap S$ must be a subset of $K$ for every $K\in S$. However, this is just a consequence of what $\bigcap S$ means -- if $K$ is some member of $S$, then by definition every element of $\bigcap S$ must be in $K$.

This proves that $\bigcap S$ is a subgroup generated by $A$, as promised.

Answer (score 3):

Closure under the group operation of $G$ ensures that if $a\in G$, then $a^n\in G$ for all positive integers $n$. Since $a^{-1}\in G$, again by closure we have $(a^{-1})^n \in G$ for all positive integers $n$. Since $(a^{-1})^n = (a^n)^{-1}$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$ (which can be shown by induction), we have that $a^n\in G$ whenever $n$ is a negative integer. So $a^n \in G$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$. Since $G$ contains all powers of $a$, $G$ contains $(a)$.

Comment: Thank You. May be I should edit my question little bit now in light of your answer. If $a \in  G$ then what is the guarantee that a cyclic subgroup $(a)$ exist. Could not " $a$ " be an element of $G$ but not generate any group. Again it could be a trivial thing to ask but better safe than sorry.